# OCR implementation using PHP

Tags: php, ocr

I am working on an application which incorporates feature to read text from image and decode information on basis of information retrieved from image.

To accomplish above feature I have integrated following library.

URL : https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php

But upon its integration it generates an error which states that

> /usr/bin/tesseract: /opt/lampp/lib/libtiff.so.5: no version
>   information available (required by /usr/lib/liblept.so.5)

It executes command internally but when same command is executed into linux terminal it executes successfully but generates an error when executed with php script.

I look forward for appropriate solution to my issue.

Comment: By `linux terminal` do you mean the PHP CLI or a shell script?

Comment: @user3783243 Command executes successfully when executed into linux terminal i.e shell script but when it is executed as a part of php script into web browser it generates an error .Hence it seems that upon execution of script into browser required dependencies not get resolved

Comment: Can you please add what you actually are running in both cases? `http://example.com/script.php` and `sh something.sh` or `php /var/www/example.com/script.php`